# How to use GROUP BY on a result with LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit, offset

I use MySQL 5.6 and I have a problem with the query results, using `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT + OFFEST`. Those results are not consistent with the results without the `OFFSET`. Why ? And what's the solution ?

This query (no `OFFSET` and no `GROUP BY`) gave me 10 results:

```
SELECT sp.couleur, sp.nom, d.degre_urgence 
FROM demande_interservices AS d 
LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_a_valider AS dv ON d.id = dv.demande_interservices_id  
LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_affectee_a_sous_pole AS d_aff ON d.id = d_aff.demande_interservices_id 
LEFT JOIN sous_pole AS sp ON d_aff.sous_pole_id = sp.id 
WHERE d.pole_sollicite_id = (SELECT pole_id FROM utilisateur WHERE id = 38) 
AND (d.statut_id = 1 OR d.statut_id = 2) 
AND dv.demande_interservices_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY d.degre_urgence DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Results:

```
couleur    degre_urgence    nom
_______________________________

#cd423a    5    Communication
#cd423a    5    Communication
#ff3ebb    5    Assistante DGS
#925210    5    Police Urbanisme
#000000    5    informatique RGPD
#cd423a    5    Communication
#ff3ebb    5    Assistante DGS
#e2c63d    5    Urbanisme - Marchés Publics
#ff3ebb    5    Assistante DGS
#925210    4    Police Urbanisme
```

The same query with the `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT sp.couleur, sp.nom, d.degre_urgence 
FROM demande_interservices AS d 
LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_a_valider AS dv ON d.id = dv.demande_interservices_id 
LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_affectee_a_sous_pole AS d_aff ON d.id = d_aff.demande_interservices_id 
LEFT JOIN sous_pole AS sp ON d_aff.sous_pole_id = sp.id 
WHERE d.pole_sollicite_id = (SELECT pole_id FROM utilisateur WHERE id = 38) 
AND (d.statut_id = 1 OR d.statut_id = 2) 
AND dv.demande_interservices_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY nom
ORDER BY d.degre_urgence DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Results:

```
couleur    degre_urgence    nom
_______________________________

#e2c63d    5    Urbanisme - Marchés Publics
#000000    5    informatique RGPD
#925210    5    Police Urbanisme
#fff000    2    Accueil    
#7bd026    1    ASVP
#cd423a    1    Communication
#ff3ebb    1    Assistante DGS
```

But I expected these results:

```
couleur    degre_urgence    nom
_______________________________

#cd423a    5    Communication
#ff3ebb    5    Assistante DGS
#925210    5    Police Urbanisme
#000000    5    informatique RGPD
#e2c63d    5    Urbanisme - Marchés Publics
```

Comment: Is `d.degre_urgence` numeric?  Could you add these values to the example tables above to understand the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes it's an integer, between 1 and 5. I edited with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group on the result of your first query:

```
select t.nom, min(t.couleur) from (
  SELECT sp.couleur, sp.nom 
  FROM demande_interservices AS d 
  LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_a_valider AS dv ON d.id = dv.demande_interservices_id 
  LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_affectee_a_sous_pole AS d_aff ON d.id = 
  d_aff.demande_interservices_id 
  LEFT JOIN sous_pole AS sp ON d_aff.sous_pole_id = sp.id 
  WHERE d.pole_sollicite_id = (SELECT pole_id FROM utilisateur WHERE id = 38) 
  AND (d.statut_id = 1 OR d.statut_id = 2) 
  AND dv.demande_interservices_id IS NULL 
  ORDER BY d.degre_urgence DESC 
  LIMIT 10
) t
GROUP BY t.nom
```

MySql allows you to use couleur instead of min(couleur) although it's not a sql standard.

Comment: That is actually (new) standard, if `couleur` is functionally dependent on `nom`.

Comment: Oh I see, I have to do it in 2 steps, to group on the same result. It works great, thanks you !! If anyone can explain the reason why the `GROUP BY` with `LIMIT` affects the results, it would be great, I like to understand things :)

Comment: They way you want the results is: first execute the subquery, then limit its results to 10 rows only and then use grouping on these limited results. This is what I understood from your expected results.

Comment: Indeed, it's for the pagination, only 10 rows to show on each pages. And the grouping is for a caption, that must be consistent with the 10 showed rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use min() and group  by

```
SELECT min(sp.couleur), sp.nom 
FROM demande_interservices AS d 
LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_a_valider AS dv ON d.id = dv.demande_interservices_id  
  AND dv.demande_interservices_id IS NULL 
LEFT JOIN demande_interservices_affectee_a_sous_pole AS d_aff ON d.id = d_aff.demande_interservices_id 
LEFT JOIN sous_pole AS sp ON d_aff.sous_pole_id = sp.id 
WHERE d.pole_sollicite_id = ( SELECT pole_id FROM utilisateur WHERE id = 38) 
AND (d.statut_id = 1 OR d.statut_id = 2) 
GROUP BY sp.nom 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I get the same result :/

Comment: answer  updated .. for a wrong left join  .. anyway   is not possible for your data sample the same result for group by and not  .. be sure you have min(sp.couleur) in select

Comment: Again the same result. Why would this `min()` change the result ?

Comment: SELECT min(sp.couleur), sp.nom    ..and group by should redeudce  the number of rows  returned